# Select Last Record in SSRS report Designer 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report-designer

Trying to get the last/lastest record from ShipHead.Shipdate instead of all the records How do i Do last record with this query?

```
SELECT
  OrderRel.ReqDate
 ,OrderHed.EntryPerson
 ,ShipHead.ShipDate
 ,Customer.Name
 ,ShipDtl.OrderNum
 ,ShipDtl.OrderLine
 ,ShipDtl.OrderRelNum
  FROM
   OrderHed
    INNER JOIN OrderDtl
    ON OrderHed.Company = OrderDtl.Company AND OrderHed.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum
    INNER JOIN OrderRel
    ON OrderDtl.Company = OrderRel.Company AND OrderDtl.OrderNum = OrderRel.OrderNum AND         OrderDtl.OrderLine = OrderRel.OrderLine
  INNER JOIN ShipDtl
ON OrderRel.Company = ShipDtl.Company AND OrderRel.OrderNum = ShipDtl.OrderNum AND     OrderRel.OrderLine = ShipDtl.OrderLine AND OrderRel.OrderRelNum = ShipDtl.OrderRelNum
  INNER JOIN ShipHead
   ON ShipDtl.Company = ShipHead.Company AND ShipDtl.PackNum = ShipHead.PackNum
   INNER JOIN Customer
   ON ShipHead.Company = Customer.Company AND ShipHead.CustNum = Customer.CustNum
  WHERE
OrderRel.OrderNum = 603205
```

Comment: That all depends on what exactly you are determining the "last record" is. If you have a particular column you need to `ORDER BY` then I would suggest using a `TOP 1 ORDER BY DESC`

Comment: Thanks Zac But that returned only my last recored in the entire query which i guess is right.  If my shipper shipped the same order line, release in diffrent days i only want to see the last record he ship for that order.

Comment: Then you need to determine the criteria that sets that as the last row then `ORDER BY ` those columns `DESC`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean..  I am asuming I need the last record in ship.head not sure how to get there

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "last record". The last record changes depending on how you order the row set.  Example if you `SELECT TOP 1 YourQuery`  `ORDER BY ShipHead.ShipDate DESC` then you would  get the row with the most recent ShipDate. Does that make more sense.

Comment: Yes I understand,  my records look like this  Entry Person   Req Date Ship Date Order Num Order Line  Order Rel Num
Patty Driscoll   1/5/2014 0:00 1/6/2014 0:00 600000  2   1
Patty Driscoll   1/6/2014 0:00 1/6/2014 0:00 600002  2   1
Sherry Esielionis  1/14/2014 0:00 1/14/2014 0:00 600006  6   1
Sherry Esielionis  1/14/2014 0:00 1/14/2014 0:00 600006  1   1
Sherry Esielionis  1/15/2014 0:00 1/14/2014 0:00 600006  1   1

Comment: @user1017175: As you can see, comments are not well suited for posting data samples. Your question would be a better place for that, and not only because you can align your sample nicely in your question, but also because that's the place to post it in the first place, so that other could see and possibly understand your issue better. It would actually be great if in addition to your data sample you also posted the desired result for it.

Comment: Do i just edit my orginal question?

Comment: Yes, just edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. If you wanted the last dated record for each entry person then change to the B:

```
SELECT 
    X.ReqDate,
    X.EntryPerson,
    X.ShipDate,
    X.Name,
    X.OrderNum,
    X.OrderLine,
    X.OrderRelNum
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    ORl.ReqDate,
    OH.EntryPerson,
    SH.ShipDate,
    rn = row_number() OVER(ORDER BY SH.ShipDate DESC),
    --rn = row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY OH.EntryPerson ORDER BY SH.ShipDate DESC) --<<B
    C.Name,
    SD.OrderNum,
    SD.OrderLine,
    SD.OrderRelNum
  FROM
    OrderHed OH
    INNER JOIN OrderDtl OD ON 
        OH.Company = OD.Company AND 
        OH.OrderNum = OD.OrderNum
    INNER JOIN OrderRel ORl ON 
        OD.Company = ORl.Company AND 
        OD.OrderNum = ORl.OrderNum AND         
        OD.OrderLine = ORl.OrderLine
    INNER JOIN ShipDtl SD ON 
        ORl.Company = SD.Company AND 
        ORl.OrderNum = SD.OrderNum AND     
        ORl.OrderLine = SD.OrderLine AND 
        ORl.OrderRelNum = SD.OrderRelNum
    INNER JOIN ShipHead SH ON
        SD.Company = SH.Company AND 
        SD.PackNum = SH.PackNum
    INNER JOIN Customer C ON 
        SH.Company = C.Company AND 
        SH.CustNum = C.CustNum
    WHERE
      ORl.OrderNum = 603205
  ) X
WHERE X.rn = 1
```

P.S. why don't you use shorter aliases - that is part of the point of aliases

Comment: Whytheq, this gave me an error i am working in report builder 3.0 if that makes a diffrence